# IHttpHandler won't accept DELETE or PUT requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a .ashx file that I would like to people to call DELETE requests to.  I always get a 405 Method not allowed error.  I have been doing some research and I have found a lot of stuff about changing the web.config because IIS needs to allow those type of requests.  Any ideas?  I am using sharepoint and I need to modify the webconfig file.  Here is a part of the web.config file:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read,Execute,Script">
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <remove name="svc-Integrated" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="OwssvrHandler" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\isapi\owssvr.dll" path="/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="JSONHandlerFactory" path="*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebPart" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebPart.axd" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts.WebPartHttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControl" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

</handlers>
```

EDIT:

I am using IIS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS7, make sure you have DELETE specified in allowed verbs.

```
Sites > Default Web Site > [your app] > Request Filtering > Http Verbs Pane
```